# android: saving speech recognition including its result

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Sorry about the title as I was not able to guess the title of this question.

Ok so, I am working on my application which needs to be activated using voice command, (same as Google's Google Now launcher app, we just need to say, "Ok google"...)

So, I dont want my Sppech recognition engine, to send audio to google servers everytime, I give voice command. Is there any way to store this whole procedure for offline use ?

I want to have some commands that my app would recognize offline, and act accordingly. Like, "Hello Note", "Add Note", etc...

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PocketSphinx is a popular choice for offline speech recognition on Android, see http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid